# Aptitude. Шаблоны поиска

Tags: linux, apt-get

```
apt-get purge avahi*
```

Выдаст все пакеты, которые начинаются на *avahi* (символ * - любые символы после)

```
aptitude purge avahi*
```

Тоже для *aptitude* выведет : Не удалось найти пакеты, содержащих «avahi*» в своём имени или описании.

Так что, для *aptitude* шаблоны не действуют, или есть другой способ? Или можно как-то настроить?

Comment: В `aptitude` используются поисковые шаблоны тильды "~" и знака вопроса "?". https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/rn01re01.ru.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

аналогом этой команды:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge 'avahi*'
```

можно считать примерно такую конструкцию:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge '?installed?name(^avahi)'
```

или, более коротко:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge '~i~n^avahi'
```

---

[руководство по поисковым терминам](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.ru.html)